# Full Calendar Customization for showing 2 rows of weeeks at once

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to customize the view of full calendar.
I use full calendar 3.0.
I want to customize as below screen.

[image: target image]

I want to show 2 weeks as top and above, so want to show 2 weeks at once.
I can show 2 weeks at one column

```
duration: {
   days: 14
},
```

but by this way, I only show 2 weeks in one column.

[image: current screen]

If someone knows, plz help me
Thanks

Comment: If you want to get the view like your first picture then you need to put two copies of fullCalendar on your page.

Comment: Thanks. I think my first image looks like wrong.   My purpose is to show 2 weeks at once in 1 screen. means 2 rows of weeks in 1 screen .  thanks.

Comment: fullCalendar does not support that. That's why I say that you have to put two calendars in your page to get that effect. It's the only way, unless you are prepared to spend a **lot** of time making a [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js)

Comment: Thanks ADyson. will try that.